# How Create intent for an activityTwo

Tags: java, android

Im new on Java so its confusing me a little bit, i want to create an intent for Activity two but there seem to be a problem with the code that i have written.

```html
               @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO:
                    // Launch Activity Two
                    // Hint: use Context's startActivity() method

                    // Create an intent stating which Activity you would like to
                    // start

                    Intent activityTwo = new Intent(ActivityTwo.this.finish());


                    Intent intent = null;

                    // Launch the Activity using the intent
                    startActivity(activityTwo);
                }
            });

            // Has previous state been saved?
            if (savedInstanceState != null) {

                // TODO:
                // Restore value of counters from saved state
                super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
                mCreate = savedInstanceState.getInt(CREATE_KEY);
                mRestart = savedInstanceState.getInt(RESTART_KEY);
                mStart = savedInstanceState.getInt(START_KEY);




            }

  // Emit LogCat message
  Log.i(TAG, "Entered the onCreate() method");

  // TODO:
```

Answer (score 0):

from First to Second:

```
Button next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Second.class);
    intent.putExtra("Tag", "Value");
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
}});
```

Second to First:

```
Button previous= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
previous.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),First.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}});
```

Answer (score 0):

First Understand the concept of Intent.

In your case, you want to call ActivityTwo from ActivityOne.

follow this steps

- Create ActivityTwo.
- Declare ActivityTwo in your AndroidManifest.xml

> `<activity android:name=".ActivityTwo" />`

- Write Intent code where in onclick() method.

> ```
> Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),ActivityTwo.class);
> startActivity(intent);
> ```

In this code Intent Constructor contains two parameters.

1. Current Context
2. ActivityTwo reference.

Comment: Thanks alot guys, i made a couple of mistakes

Comment: Thanks alot guys i made a lot if mistakes in my coding, first i didn't declare "ActivityTwo" in the Manifest and secondly the code i wrote there was a mess. i hope you guys dont mind if i ask you questions every now and then

Comment: If you have solved your problem, kindly make it as a correct answer so that other developer will not repeat such mistake :)